# What is wrong with trying to print the name of the student?

Tags: python, oop

This is my code. I was trying to print the name of a student but i received a lot of errors. what did i do wrong? Thank you very much!

```
class Elev:
"""
Un elev are nume, cnp,clasa,
"""
def __init__(self,nume,cnp,clasa):
    self.nume=nume
    self.cnp=cnp
    self.clasa=clasa
def set_nume(self,nume):
    self.nume=nume
def get_nume(self):
    return self.nume
def set_clasa(self,clasa):
    self.clasa=clasa
def get_clasa(self):
    return self.clasa
def set_cnp(self,cnp):
    self.cnp=cnp
def get_cnp(self):
    return self.cnp
def merg(self):
    print("Merge la ore")
def __str__(self):
    return "%s"(self.nume)
```

This is the second class i used:

```
class Student(Elev):
def __init__(self,nume,cnp,an):
    self.an=an
    super().__init__(self,nume,cnp)
def Vacanta(self):
    print("Nu ai restanta ai vacanta!!!!!")
```

here us how i called the classes and functions

```
def Main():
student=Student("Popescu Vasile",232423423,1)
print(student.get_nume())

Main()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:/Facultate/Python/tema_mostenire/tema_mostenire.py", line 36, in <module> Main() File "D:/Facultate/Python/tema_mostenire/tema_mostenire.py", line 34, in Main print(student.get_nume()) File "D:/Facultate/Python/tema_mostenire/tema_mostenire.py", line 24, in str return "%s"(self.nume) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you  post what  errors you are getting ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Facultate/Python/tema_mostenire/tema_mostenire.py", line 36, in <module>
    Main()
  File "D:/Facultate/Python/tema_mostenire/tema_mostenire.py", line 34, in Main
    print(student.get_nume())
  File "D:/Facultate/Python/tema_mostenire/tema_mostenire.py", line 24, in __str__
    return "%s"(self.nume)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Edit you post with the error messages to get all information in the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the indentation there's two issues with your code:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%s"(self.nume)
```

Above is not valid Python code, you can either add `%` operator as Daniel suggested or you can just modify it to return the name:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.nume
```

The second issue is with the way you call parent class constructor here:

```
def __init__(self,nume,cnp,an):
    self.an=an
    super().__init__(self,nume,cnp)
```

When [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#super) is called without parameters you don't need to supply `self` parameter but you need to supply all three other parameters that parent expects:

```
def __init__(self,nume,cnp,an):
    self.an=an
    super().__init__(nume,cnp, 'foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `__str__` method is missing the `%` operator:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.nume)
```

If you used proper style, with a space between operators, this would have been easier to see.

Comment: And I get this error  : RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Answer (score 0):

From the error you got ,it looks like the problem was the last function of the class.See below:

```
class Elev:
 "" Un elev are nume, cnp,clasa, """
 def __init__(self,nume,cnp,clasa):            self.nume=nume self.cnp=cnp self.clasa=clasa 
def set_nume(self,nume): self.nume=nume 
    def get_nume(self): 
    return self.nume 
    def set_clasa(self,clasa): self.clasa=clasa 
    def get_clasa(self): 
    return self.clasa 
    def set_cnp(self,cnp): 
    self.cnp=cnp 
    def get_cnp(self): 
    return self.cnp 
    def merg(self): 
    print("Merge la ore") 
    def __str__(self):
    return "%s" %  (self.nume) #fixed
```